# Counting node type in View throws SQL error

Tags: 8, views

I have field Content:Type that I aggregate with COUNT to show the number of nodes of that specific content type. But I get this SQL error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated
> query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains
> nonaggregated column 'db.node_field_data.nid'; this is incompatible
> with sql_mode=only_full_group_by: SELECT "node_field_data"."nid" AS
> "nid", COUNT(node_field_data.type) AS "node_field_data_type" FROM
> "node_field_data" "node_field_data" WHERE ("node_field_data"."status"
> = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND ("node_field_data"."type" IN (:db_condition_placeholder_1)); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0]
> => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => content_type )

Comment: Did you add any GROUP BY on each aggregated filter?

Comment: Hm, no, and I don't see any possibility to do that...